# "Connectedness" In Randomly Generated Graphs

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

For past 3-4 days I have been playing with implementing graphs, and associated structures in python. among other things, i have a trivial function to generate random-graphs i.e. graphs in which two vertices are connected with a given probability. the graphs are then displayed using graphviz.

anyways, during the course of above activity, i noticed that above certain probability almost all graphs with a given number of vertices are always connected. couple of questions:

- Are there other "properties" that go through a similar "transition"?
- I am sure someone else must have examined this whole thing more rigorously. any pointers?

Comment: Better suited for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: And see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model#Properties_of_G.28n.2C_p.29 for the properties.

Answer (score 5):

Good question!

In fact, the subject of random graphs is well known and dates back to Erdos and Renyi, 1959.

The observation of threshold is also excellent. There are other properties of graphs which share this "threshold" phenomena.

In fact, it has been proven that most "monotone" properties share this "threshold" property. This was proven by Erdös and Rényi (according the the book mentioned below).

A property P is monotone if a graph H on n vertices has P implies any supergraph G (on n vertices) of H (i.e H is a subgraph of G) also has P. For example, Hamiltonian Cycle is one such property. Connectedness is another.

Note: This definition of monotonicity might differ from other texts on graph-theory. I am mentioning the one provided in the book below.

The book [Random Graphs](http://books.google.com/books?id=o9WecWgilzYC) by Béla Bollobás should get you started. See page 40 for a discussion about the monotone properties having a "threshold". I must warn you though, that book uses some pretty heavy mathematics.